# Fix wordpress rendering due to different ip address used upon creation of vulnerable machine

Tags: wordpress, virtual-machine, ip-address, hosts

I have a vulnerable virtual machine running on my computer, https://www.vulnhub.com/entry/evm-1,391/ I found a wordpress directory but the page wont render correctly because the creator made all links point to 192.168.56.103, but on my network it has an ip address of 192.168.1.83. How do I somehow change the ip address to the correct ip? I remember watching an ippsec video and he had a small fix there but i can't find it. He edited his hosts file, but I don't think it will work in my situation. 
I tried editing my /etc/hosts file to

```
192.168.1.83    192.168.56.103
```

and

```
192.168.56.103    192.168.1.83
```

but none of those worked. I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

First you should edit your "WordPress URL" and "Site-URL" in the WP settings menu. Then: there are plugins for database "search and replace". You can search all database tables for `192.168.56.103` and replace them with `192.168.1.83`. Then open all files in your (child-) themes directory and replace the hardcoded IP (if any) with the new one.

Make DB and child-theme backups first.

Regards Tom

Comment: Well, here's the thing. I don't own the vulnerable machine, so I need another way. However, I have contacted the machine creator and let him know about my issue. Thanks for the help though.